# GLEW crashing in XCode

Tags: xcode, cocoa, opengl, glew, glfw

I'm trying to run a simple OpenGL program using GLFW (version 3.0.2) and GLEW (version 1.10.0) in XCode (version 4.6.3) on OS X 10.8.4. The entire code is shown below.

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <OpenGL/OpenGL.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void RenderScene()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
}

void InitGL()
{
    glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
}

void ErrorFunc(int code, const char *msg)
{
    cerr << "Error " << code << ": " << msg << endl;
}

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Report errors */
    glfwSetErrorCallback(ErrorFunc);

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    /* Window hints */
    glfwWindowHint (GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR,  3);
    glfwWindowHint (GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR,  2);
    glfwWindowHint (GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint (GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE,        GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    /* Initialize OpenGL */
    InitGL();

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        RenderScene();

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Most of this came straight from GLFW's documentation; only the rendering function and GLEW initialization are mine. I have added frameworks for OpenGL, Cocoa and IOKit and linked against libGLEW.a and libglfw3.a. The program compiles successfully but appears to crash when attempting to execute functions GLEW was supposed to take care of. Here, the program crashes on `glClearBufferfv`. If I comment that out, I get a window with a black background. My guess is GLEW is secretly not working, since it reports no errors but doesn't seem to be doing its job at all.

The exact error message XCode throws at me is `error: address doesn't contain a section that points to a section in a object file` with an error code of `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. If I replace `glClearBufferfv` with `glClearColor` the program doesn't crash, but still has a black background when it should actually be red. When queried, OpenGL returns the version string `2.1 NVIDIA-8.12.47 310.40.00.05f01`, which explains why calls to newer functions aren't working, but shouldn't GLEW have set up the correct OpenGL context? Moreover, GLFW's documentation says that they've been creating OpenGL 3+ contexts since GLFW 2.7.2. I really don't know what to do.

Comment: Without GLEW, XCode complains that `glClearBufferfv` isn't defined. If I use `glClearColor` instead, it runs but always gives me black regardless of what color I specify.

Comment: Forcibly setting the desired version of OpenGL with `glfwWindowHint` doesn't appear to work either. It crashes for any version above 2.1...

Comment: GLEW doesn't create an OpenGL context; it relies on the application to have created one before it goes off to fetch all its functions.  In your case, I think GLFW will create the OpenGL context.

Comment: @JonathanPeck: I suspect it crashes for you when you try anything above 2.1 for the OpenGL version because OS X is _very_ particular about the version. It will usually fail for any major/minor version combination that is not *exactly* **3.2 Core**.

Answer (score 3):

`glClearBuffer (...)` is an OpenGL 3.0 function, it is not implemented in all versions of OS X (some only implement OpenGL 2.1). Because OS X does not use *runtime* extensions, GLEW is not going to fix this problem for you.

You will have to resort to the traditional method for clearing buffers in older versions of OS X (10.6 or older). This means setting the "clear color" and then clearing the color buffer as a two-step process. Instead of a single function call that can clear a specific buffer to a specific value, use this:

```
#define USE_GL3     // This code requires OpenGL 3.0, comment out if unavailable

void RenderScene()
{
    GLfloat color[] = {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};

#ifdef USE_GL3      // Any system that implements OpenGL 3.0+
    glClearBufferfv (GL_COLOR, 0, color);
#else               // Any other system
    glClearColor    (color [0], color [1], color [2]);
    glClear         (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
#endif
}
```

This is not ideal, however. There is no point in setting the clear color multiple times. You should set the clear color one time when you initialize the application and replace the `! USE_GL3` branch of the code with `glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);`

---

Now, because you mentioned you are using Mac OS X 10.8, you can ignore a lot of what I wrote above. OS X 10.8 actually implements OpenGL 3.2 if you do things correctly.

You need two things for `glClearBuffer (...)` to work on OS X:

1. Mac OS X 10.7+ (which you have)
2. Tell glfw to create an OpenGL 3.2 core context

Before you create your window in glfw, add the following code:

```
glfwWindowHint (GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MAJOR,  3);
glfwWindowHint (GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MINOR,  2);
glfwWindowHint (GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
glfwWindowHint (GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE,        GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
```

Once you have an OpenGL 3.2 core context, you can also eliminate the whole `! USE_GL3` pre-processor branch from your code. This was a provision to allow your code to work on OS X implementations that do not support OpenGL 3.2.

Comment: When I set those parameters, window creation fails with the error `65544: Entry point retrieval is broken`. The only thing I managed to find out about this error, is that it means a call to `glfwGetProcAddress("glGetStringi")` failed.

Comment: @JonathanPeck: Updated my answer to include the forward compatibility bit. Try the new series of hints and see if they fix your problem.

Comment: Same error: `entry point retrieval is broken`. Without those hints, I do have a fully functional 2.1 context, but my system is supposed to be able to go up to 3.2.

Comment: All the GLEW stuff is gone. I even started a completely new project just to make sure.

Comment: @JonathanPeck: I don't know what to tell you, everything looks correct. The only thing I can think of is you're not using a version of the OS X SDK for 10.7+ in XCode, still linking to GLEW or using the wrong version of glfw.

Answer (score 0):

GLEW doesn't really work on mac unless you enable the experimental option. Enable it after setting all your stuff in GLFW.

```
glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
```

**Edit:**

And you also set to use OpenGL Core with

```
glfwOpenWindowHint( GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MAJOR, 3 );
glfwOpenWindowHint( GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MINOR, 2 );
```

Slightly different from yours.

Comment: That allows me to call functions like `glClearBuffer` without everything crashing, but I'm still left with an OpenGL 2.1 context.

Comment: Don't have time now, so I just copied a simple sample code I had from before. I'll see if I can do anything later, but here you go. http://pastebin.com/9JvCVbxH